# teewpy Access Token must be provided for OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow with PKCE

Tags: twitter, tweepy

i'm trying to like a specific tweet with tweet id but i'm facing below error

TypeError: Access Token must be provided for OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow with PKCE

```
 import tweepy
 client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key="",consumer_secret="",access_token="",access_token_secret="")
 client.like(tweet.data['id'],user_auth=False )
```

how to fix the code